# How to use de elm-markdown module in Elm?

Tags: package, markdown, elm

I am completely new to Elm, and I am going through the [examples](http://elm-lang.org/examples) to get acquainted with the language. The problem is that I can not run the markdown example.

The code is as follows:

```
import Markdown

main = Markdown.toHtml [] markdown

markdown = """

# This is Markdown

[Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) lets you
write content in a really natural way.

* You can have lists, like this one
* Make things **bold** or *italic*
* Embed snippets of `code`
* Create [links](/)
* ...

The [elm-markdown][] package parses all this content, allowing you
to easily generate blocks of `Element` or `Html`.

[elm-markdown]: http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-markdown/latest

"""
```

But when I try to compile it I get the following message:

```
I cannot find module 'Markdown'.

Module 'Main' is trying to import it.

Potential problems could be:
  * Misspelled the module name
  * Need to add a source directory or new dependency to elm-package.json
```

I have already installed the module with the command

```
$ elm-package install evancz/elm-markdown
```

Any explanation of what is happening and how to fix it will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it just Markdown module you are not being able to use?  The code and procedure looks fine to me (I cannot reproduce it).

Comment: Did you run the `elm package install` command in the same directory where you are trying to build the code? To verify, you can run the command again, or just look to see that there is an `elm-stuff` directory

Comment: @ChadGilbert That was the problem. I assumed the `elm-package install` would do a system wild installation. Once I execute the command in the same directory where I was trying to compile the program it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to run the `elm package install` command in the same directory where you are trying to build the code. To verify, you can look to see that there is an `elm-stuff` directory.

Package installations are local to the project itself. They aren't system wide, so if you start a new project, you'll have to run `elm package install` in that directory too.

In rare circumstances I've also seen that error message occur even though the package is installed. While I can't determine what caused the problem, deleting the `elm-stuff` and running just `elm package install` (no other arguments) from the project root fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The steps to be followed:

- Install the Elm with a configure editor (Atom App one of the good ELM Plugin)
- Once you done with installation follow the given steps @https://atom.io/packages/language-elm
- Once you practicing the example codes using "http://elm-lang.org/examples" you may tried copying the same code and it showing the above error
- You can see these video for the basic code like "Hello Word" using these you will get an idea where to fix "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rf2CkojtxFw"
- Delete the **"ELM-STUFF"** from the package try to run these command "elm package install" and then above command " elm-package install evancz/elm-markdown" and then try to run the "elm-reactor"
- It will work :-)